# String comparison gives strange results

Tags: python, string-comparison

Why after concatination result changed?

```
b = "test"+str(1)
a = "test"+str(1)
print(a is b) # False

b2 = "test"+"1"
a2 = "test"+"1"
print(a2 is b2) # True ???
```

Comment: `"test"+"1"` is merged into `"test1"` through optimization at compilation time, so they share the same constant reference at bytecode level. The result of `"test"+str(1)` on the other hand is not evaluated and created until runtime.

Comment: [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988)